# Gimbal motor periodically shaking back and forth instead of spinning

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am using the [BGMC2 (http://www.rovertec.com/products-bgmc2.html)](http://www.rovertec.com/products-bgmc2.html) to control a [gimbal motor (http://www.iflight-rc.com/ipower-motor-gbm5208h-200t-brushless-gimbal-motor-with-as5048a-encoder.html)](http://www.iflight-rc.com/ipower-motor-gbm5208h-200t-brushless-gimbal-motor-with-as5048a-encoder.html).  I am running the following code on my Raspberry pi to send the controller a PWM signal:

```
import os
import time
os.system("sudo pigpiod") #launch GPIO library
time.sleep(1)
import pigpio

ESC = 4
# white wire to 4 (7)
# black wire to 23 (6)

pi = pigpio.pi();
pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(ESC, 0)

max_value = 2500
min_value = 500

def control():
    print "Starting motor"
    time.sleep(1)
    speed = 1900
    while True:
        pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(ESC, speed)

def arm():
    print "Connect battery and press Enter"
    inp = raw_input()
    if inp == '':
        pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(ESC, 0)
        time.sleep(1)
        pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(ESC, max_value)
        time.sleep(1)
        pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(ESC, min_value)
        time.sleep(1)
        control()

print "Starting..."
arm()
```

Here is the schematic we built:
[image]

I noticed that the controller regularly flashes the RED light labeled D2 and my gimbal motor shakes back and forth while this is happening.  I was wondering how I could go about debugging this problem to prevent the motor from shaking back and forth.

Comment: Can you post a schematic or diagram of how you have things wired?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Ok I have added a schematic of the wiring.

Comment: What happens if you just do `pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(ESC, speed)` once instead of continuously?

Comment: If your "minimum" pulse width is 250, why are you setting it to zero?

Comment: @RonBeyer -- (I'm working with him on the project) -- He is following the instructions from this link to control a brushless motor (not gimbal) - http://www.instructables.com/id/Driving-an-ESCBrushless-Motor-Using-Raspberry-Pi/ - We assumed if we replaced the ESC motor controller with a gimbal motor controller it would work out.  I think he sets it to 0, then max, then min to calibrate the motor.

Comment: @ronbeyer also setting the pulse width to 0 would just turn off the motor.